# List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (20: Not a directory)

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, apt

When I executed `sudo apt update` I'm getting

```
Reading package lists... Done
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (20: Not a directory)
```

Also, I was getting a status error which I solved using

```
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

I tried  `sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial` as suggested in few other threads

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Not a directory
```

Even I tried `sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/`

Any other solution?

Comment: Prior to this same issue arising in my docker file, there was an earlier error in the logs to say => ERROR [3/3] RUN apt-get update. 

Who would imagine that this would be related to the user permissions! Upon careful inspected noted this error and that's how I landed in this post and the below answer from @ssi-anik helped resolve the issue. Adding this comment so Google may search this page as the first result for both these issues! ;) Thanks all.

Comment: I had this after trying to clean apt after a bad install. This helped: https://askubuntu.com/a/358971/1718249

Answer (score 143):

The answer may be inappropriate here. But as I came here others may land here too.

If you're using docker and you face the same issue you can do like the following.

```
USER root
# RUN commands
USER 1001
```

Reference: [Link](https://github.com/WASdev/ci.docker/issues/194#issuecomment-433519379)

Comment: Alternatively, if you're running after-the-fact (e.g. to check if a container needs an update), try `sudo docker run -it --rm --user 0 ....`

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious: "USER 1001" assumes that that's the user you want your container (or subsequent dockerfile entry) to run as.  If you started with `FROM foo` then you'd want to put whatever user FOO configured in that place.

Comment: This answer is still valid in 2021 - fixed my issue just now.  Thanks.

Comment: AND still valid in 2024. We had a container where the developer was running as non-root and the problem was once again fixed by this solution. It's frustrating nothing in the symptoms points to a user permissions issue.

Answer (score 26):

You can try adding `-u 0` in the command

> sudo docker exec -u 0 -it ContainerID bin/bash

According to Docker, the u flag defines what username or UID in the system for the container to run as, setting `-u 0` means you run the container as `root`, use it with caution! [Reference here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

Answer (score 3):

The same happened to me. I follow as guide this answer:[The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened](https://askubuntu.com/questions/358560/eread-error-read-5-input-output-error-ethe-package-lists-or-status-file)

I assumed my lists were corrupted. I went to `/var/lib/apt/` I saw a file (lists@) instead of a directory. I deleted it (`sudo rm lists`) and re-created the path (`sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`). Double-check the path gets created.

Answer (score 3):

this is how it works access as `root` in docker bash and install your apps

get id container by name

```
sudo docker ps -aqf "name=name=es01"
```

access bash as `root`

```
sudo docker exec -u 0 -it 3d42134dfd59 bash
```

Example install:

```
apt get update
apt-get install nano
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue while trying to build a new container and experimenting with `Dockerfile` for a while.
What saved me finally was just to delete all containers I've created during this process using `docker rm`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when using bitnami spark image and docker exec command with arguments -u didn't work for me. I found my answer in the image documentation [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/tutorials/work-with-non-root-containers/).

In case you are using a docker image, it might be that the image is a non root container image. Read the documents of the docker image provider to find the solution to see how you can use the image as a root container image.

Comment: The same works with apache/spark-py image as well. Just specify `user:root` after image in docker compose file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when trying to install an **Typora** on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

I was running into the error whenever I run the command below:

```
# add Typora's repository

sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://typora.io/linux ./'
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

I disconnected and reconnected my network connection, and when I ran the command again, it worked fine.

I think it was an issue with my network connectivity.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

You first need to have super user privilege by typing in `sudo -i` and then inserting your password.