# Azure CLI not found in Jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops, command-line-interface, jenkins-plugins

I have install azure cli plugins in jenkins after that  i setup Azure Service Principal and got ***Successfully verified the Microsoft Azure Service Principal*** after that i create a new job and added az version to check az is installed or not in it and got failed error below is the screenshot of that error

Note:- My Jenkins is having v2.332.1 and installed in AKS Cluster as a Helm chat my jenkins is running

[image]

Here is the screenshot of plugin installed
[image]

Here is the my job new create in freestylejob
[image]

Please help out with this issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to install azure cli in the Jenkins Host as well.

from
https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-cli/   - Prerequisites

> To use this plugin, first you need to have an Azure Service Principal
> in your Jenkins instance.
>
> 1.Create an Azure Service Principal through Azure CLI or Azure portal.

> 2.Open Jenkins dashboard, go to Credentials, add a new Microsoft Azure Service Principal with the credential information you just created.

> 3.Install Azure CLI in the Jenkins Host

from your description, I can see you have 1,2 steps completed and possibly 3 is missing.

Comment: Where is Jenkins Host i dont know it and i have one cluster in azure in that i have install jenkins

Comment: The Container instance where you installed your Jenkins.  Can you share , how did you install jenkins, May be share your helm spec. There is a provision in Helm to run commands  post install . There you can install azure cli .

Comment: i have install Jenkins using through this  link https://bitnami.com/stack/jenkins/helm and i have create new cluster in azure in that i install Jenkins using helm..after that i browser the Jenkins start using it...i install plugin of azure-cli then setup azure service principal after that i create a new job using freestyle in that i select azure service principal after that i selected command i added az version to  check whether its install or not got failed with above error on my question

Comment: i login into pod of jenkins its not install az in pod ..im using apt update and then install azure-cli none work into pod

Comment: login to the machine and try this  curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | sudo bash    . More details on how to install az cli can be found here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt

Comment: getting error 
"I have no name!@my-release-jenkins-6b5cc48f49-6926p:/$ curl -sL aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash     
Reading package lists... Done
E: List directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial is missing. - Acquire (2: No such file or directory)"

Comment: This is because , you do not have permission. Mostly you will be using a non root container image.  Refer here and see if that helps :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56579468/list-directory-var-lib-apt-lists-partial-is-missing-acquire-20-not-a-direc

Comment: above one is for docker i need in Kubernetes pod to how to do that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793382/exec-commands-on-kubernetes-pods-with-root-access

Comment: im getting struck o root ID because when i login into nodes i run docker ps or docker images its return docker not found and i cannot ssh after that because of root ID issue

Comment: are there any different and easy method to install azure cli in jenkins host..or can i install jenkins with different method like not through helm chart

Comment: https://jenkins-x.io/docs/install-setup/

Comment: https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/opensource/2019/03/06/jenkins-x-azure-kubernetes-service-setup/